# i have created two templates one inside the project and another inside the app and error is coming template does not exist

Tags: django

1. **views.py

   from django.shortcuts import render from django.urls import
   reverse_lazy from django.http import HttpResponse from
   django.views.generic import (View,TemplateView,
                                   ListView,DetailView,
                                   CreateView,DeleteView,
                                   UpdateView) from . import models

   ## Create your views here.

   ## Original Function View:

   #

   ## def index(request):

   ## return render(request,'index.html')

   #
   #

   ## Pretty simple right? class IndexView(TemplateView):

   ```
   # Just set this Class Object Attribute to the template page.
   # template_name = 'app_name/site.html'
   template_name = 'index.html'
   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
       context  = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['injectme'] = "Basic Injection!"
       return context class SchoolListView(ListView):
   # If you don't pass in this attribute,
   # Django will auto create a context name
   # for you with object_list!
   # Default would be 'school_list'
   # Example of making your own:
   # context_object_name = 'schools'
   model = models.School class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
   context_object_name = 'school_details'
   model = models.School
   template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html' class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
   fields = ("name","principal","location")
   model = models.School class SchoolUpdateView(UpdateView):
   fields = ("name","principal")
   model = models.School class SchoolDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = models.School
   success_url = reverse_lazy("basic_app:list") class CBView(View):
   def get(self,request):
       return HttpResponse('Class Based Views are Cool!')
   ```

   urls.py of application

   from django.urls import path from . import views app_name =
   'basic_app' urlpatterns = [
       path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
       ]

   [list of files in project][1]

   1. List item

      urls.py of project from django.contrib import admin from
      django.urls import path, include from basic_app import views
      urlpatterns = [
      path('',views.IndexView.as_view()),
      path('admin/',admin.site.urls,name='admin'),
      path('basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls',namespace='basic_app')),
      ]

   settings.py """ Django settings for advcbv project. Generated by
   'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5. For more information
   on this file, see
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/ For the full
   list of settings and their values, see
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/ """ import os

   ## Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...) BASE_DIR =

   os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)))
   TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template')

   ## Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production

   ## See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

   ## SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! SECRET_KEY = '=f%ns04d@z9na8xh(kfo8v8aa-v2p0bcn^jukrh4dm_^=zq70$'

   ## SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

   ## Application definition INSTALLED_APPS = [

   ```
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'basic_app.apps.BasicAppConfig', ] MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ] ROOT_URLCONF = 'advcbv.urls' TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
       },
   }, ] WSGI_APPLICATION = 'advcbv.wsgi.application'
   ```

   ## Database

   ## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases DATABASES = {

   ```
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
   } }
   ```

   ## Password validation

   ## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

   AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
       {
           'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
       },
       {
           'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
       },
       {
           'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
       },
       {
           'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
       }, ]

   ## Internationalization

   ## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/ LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' USE_I18N = True USE_L10N = True USE_TZ =

   True

   ## Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

   ## https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/ STATIC_URL = '/static/'**

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYtk9.png

Answer (score 1):

You have to dell Django that there exist more templates in your apps/dir like so:

**Settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'My_App/templates'), # root to your apps templates
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```